# Fotorama - how to show both, dots navigation and thumbs navigation

Tags: magento2.3, gallery, fotorama, fotorama-slider

Is it possible to show both, dots navigation and thumbs navigation in product page?
Like in picture. Thank You.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fotorama only supports dots or thumbnails, not both. The possible [options](https://fotorama.io/docs/4/options/) are `'dots'`, `'thumbs'` and `false`.

I mean it's possible as is pretty much anything, but would require editing Fotorama. I'd most likely choose a more modern carousel if this was a strict requirement as Fotorama hasn't been updated in around 7 years.

[Docs](https://fotorama.io/docs/4/thumbnails/)

Comment: Hi @All
I have the same requirement.
Any solution for this to add both thumbs and dots. Please help

Comment: @kirankumar if it's a hard requirements I recommend building a custom gallery using a carousel that supports that such as https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Can you share how to implement it,

Comment: Loop through the images, initiate a carousel adding the thumbns and dot settings, add some CSS